# How do I install newer openjdk-x-jre packages using apt and vanilla Debian?

Tags: debian, aptitude

My current environment is `SMP Debian 4.19.132-1`

When I try to run `sudo apt search openjdk-14` nothing shows up when I run `sudo apt search openjdk` only 11 shows up. Per another question I tried adding non-free to my sources.list file, however, I still cannot find the package. This is **vanilla Debian not Ubuntu** so I am not sure if I need to do something different. I know I can download the zip but I would like to do it using apt.

Answer (score 1):

Debian has [openjdk-14](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=openjdk-14) only in Debian 11 bullseye (testing) and sid. It is not available in Debian 10 buster (which you have) or earlier.

Comment: could I still build from source or is there a reason it isn't included?

Comment: @Jackie Debian intends to be a stable distribution, for some definition of stable, and as such they usually ship older versions of software. Sometimes extremely old. If you need newer software than Debian typically provides, you should probably choose another distribution.

Comment: I downloaded the testing ISO but it says that it is missing drivers. I created an iso with the non-free drivers but it still isn't working so this may be trickier than just switching isos.

Comment: This one looks like it is working a bit better https://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/bullseye_di_alpha2/amd64/iso-dvd/